# Magento 2.4.3 - How To disable Page Builder?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, page-builder, migrate

I migrate my Magento from M2.4.2 to M2.4.3 but I have some issues due to page builder functionality, please give suggestions for disable page builder functionality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow these steps to deactivate Page Builder in the Admin UI:

1. In the Stores tab, select Configuration under the Settings group.
2. In the General group on the page, select Content Management.
3. Under Advanced Content Tools, select No for Enable Page Builder.

[image]

4. Click Save Config

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't use the page builder (and don't plan on using it) is to remove the module and all of it's dependencies. This way you get rid of a lot of bloat it introduces. Just add this to your `composer.json`:

```
"replace": {
    "magento/page-builder": "*"
}
```

and then run this command:

```
composer update magento/page-builder
```