# Enable Page builder editor instead of WYSIWYG Adminhtml Form Magento 2

Tags: magento2, page-builder, editor

I am using third party extension. I want to add the Page-builder editor instead of the WYSIWYG editor in the adminhtml form. Can anyone help?

Check the current code,

[image]

want to display pagebuilder in the admin form.

[image]

Comment: Can you please enable page builder from admin : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/344466/magento-2-4-3-how-to-disable-page-builder

Comment: @Msquare, it is enabled.

Comment: Hi Sunny, did you find the solution for it?

Comment: Not yet. As of now we are keeping as editor.